# changes in firebase-admin from ver5.2 to 5.10 makes my code not working

Tags: firebase-admin

I started to use firebase for a project around a year ago at the suggestion of my son who wrote an android application for a project I got. We were able to figure how to do some basic requests and everything worked fine. I noticed that the version of the firebase-admin changed a lot(I was using 5.2 and now the latest version is 6.3 and when I tried my code in a development environment for my surprise It doesn't work and I couldn't find so far documentation on the changes. Here is a snippet of my code which works with version 5.2 and would not work in version 5.11(or 6.3).

```
    ValueEventListener eventListener;
    eventListener = jobRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot technicianSnaps : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (!technicianSnaps.getKey().equals("filler")) {
                for (DataSnapshot serviceRequestsSnap : technicianSnaps.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot srSnap : serviceRequestsSnap.getChildren()) {
                        if (srSnap.child("Date").getValue() == null){
                            jobRef.child(technicianSnaps.getKey()).child(serviceRequestsSnap.getKey()).child(srSnap.getKey()).setValue(null);
                                }
```

so basically I want to delete a record which was incorrectly set in firebase and i'm trying to set the value to null. everything is set correctly and when I change to version 5.2 it deletes the record, but in version 5.11 it just gets out of the loop. it seems that the method setValue(Object value) was deprecated and other methods replaced it - setValue(Object Value, CompletionListener listener). I cannot find much info about what how CompletionListener is set and how to use it. If anyone has a link to the documentation I will try to read and understand how to change it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `setValueAsync()`, which returns a `Future` and then wait on the `Future`. The main thing that has changed is that the SDK no longer uses the `Task` API for async operations. You can find more details here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-asynchronous-operations-with-admin-java-sdk-82ca9b4f6022